# When is $\Gamma(Z, i^F) \not = \lim \Gamma(U,F)$? (F a sheaf, Z a closed subset.)

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a locally compact space. I am looking for an example of a non-compact, closed subspace $i: Z \subset X$ so that the map from $\lim \Gamma(U, F) \to \Gamma(Z,i^*F)$ is not surjective. (The colimit runs over all open sets containing Z.)

Hopefully some not too exotic space, it would be great to see this happen on $\mathbb{R}$. Mainly I am trying to figure out why this the natural map is surjective if $Z$ is compact.

Comment: The limit is over all $U$ such that $Z\subseteq U$ ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this example. Maybe one should think about it for a while to make sure all the details are correct.

Let $H=\{a+bi|b> 0\}$ be the upper half-plane then $X=\mathbb{R}\cup H$ and $Z=\mathbb{R}$. (This has nothing to do with complex numbers, its just a convenient notation, I could have used real notation.)

Now define

$$\mathcal{F}(U)=\{f| f(a)\in \mathbb{R}, f(a+bi)\in \mathbb{Z}, a,b \in \mathbb{R}, b\neq 0,$$

$$ f|U\cap \mathbb{R} \ \text{and} \ f|U\cap H  \ \text{are continuous and } \  f(a)\leq f(a+bi) \}$$

In other words the functions are real valued on $\mathbb{R}$ and integer valued on $H$ with the values of $H$ bounding those on $\mathbb{R}$. And continuous
on $\mathbb{R}$ and $H$ (thus locally constant on $H$).

Under this definition $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is an Abelian group. Restriction is just restriction of functions. It is mono and conjunctive since we are using actual set theoretic functions.

Now however $s(x)=x$ is a section in $\Gamma(\mathbb{R},i^*\mathcal{F})$ which does not extend to any open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think this is right, thanks. In particular, the main idea is that the presheaf pullback is the presheaf of bounded continuous functions on R. That sheafifies to the sheaf of continuous functions. So in particular the global sections change after sheafification.

Comment: Glad that you think is correct, I think so also. Your analysis is accurate, there are new global sections which can be extended. It is interesting to examine again the proof of the compact case in this example for say a closed interval $[0,a]$ of the reals.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to think about that case again. In this situation it seems like we get surjectivity because we can pick a new common bound on the H part using that continuous functions on compact are bounded... I am not sure how to relate this to the proof for general $Z$ compact. The reference I am reading is pretty confusing about this. Do you happen to know a good reference? Or a good hint so that I can work it out on my own?